# IE8 Flash canceling png tiling

Tags: flash, internet-explorer-8, png, tiling

I have a weird issue that only seems to show itself on IE 8 so far.

I have a semi transparent png tiling accross some divs on my site. All works ok. However as soon as i put any flash content on any div on the page, doesn't matter where, IE stops tiling the png and stretches it instead. It only occurs with flash and on ie8.

Anyone had a similar issue and does anyone know how to fix?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using 1x1 images, use 2x2 images. Somehow this solves it.

By Benjammin 
http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=204253

Comment: I believe this solved the issue a while ago, just spotted that i had not confirmed that this did